# How to use relations between a Parse subclass and an User - Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, boolean, relation

I am building a Quiz App and I have a class named "Questions" in Parse. When my user answers a question, I wanted that question to be removed from the questions that he needs to answer. I then wanted to add a subclass named "QuestionAnswered", a boolean that would return true for questions that the user had already answered. The problem is that this boolean should be unique to each user. How can I implement this in Parse and in swift?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do it is have a relation to `User` on `Questions` called `answeredBy`, and just add a user to that relation when they answer a question

```
var relation = question.relationForKey("answeredBy")
relation.addObject(aUser)
question.saveInBackground()
```

Then, to query questions that haven't been answered by the user just add a `questionQuery.whereKey("answeredBy", notEqualTo:aUser)` constraint to your question query.

I'm not sure how this will scale though, so YMMV. You might want to do some testing on this if you're expecting decent traffic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution Ricker! I was a bit worried if that would generate too much memory problems, but I guess that wont be too bad since I'm not expecting more than 300 users.